# Importing a Part of the JSON

Tags: json-format

This is JSON I'm trying to work within Mathematica:

```js
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "matrix",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "name": "scrapes"
        },
        "values": [
          [
            1556901190.699,
            "91158"
          ],
          [
            1556901220.699,
            "91160"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I need to do, is to extract values part of the JSON mentioned above and put them in the list like below for further processing:

```
Out[107]= {{1556901190.699, 91158}, {1556901220.699, 91160}}
```

I'd appreciate assistance with the implementation details.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the RawJSON Import format.

```
In[22]:= json = ImportString["{
    \"status\": \"success\",
    \"data\": {
      \"resultType\": \"matrix\",
      \"result\": [
        {
          \"metric\": {
            \"name\": \"scrapes\"
          },
          \"values\": [
            [
              1556901190.699,
              \"91158\"
            ],
            [
              1556901220.699,
              \"91160\"
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }", "RawJSON"]

Out[22]= <|"status" -> "success", 
 "data" -> <|"resultType" -> "matrix", 
   "result" -> {<|"metric" -> <|"name" -> "scrapes"|>, 
      "values" -> {{1.5569*10^9, "91158"}, {1.5569*10^9, 
         "91160"}}|>}|>|>

In[23]:= json[["data", "result", 1, "values"]]    
Out[23]= {{1.5569*10^9, "91158"}, {1.5569*10^9, "91160"}}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works as expected.